# Iterating numpy arrays and formatting into multi dimensional arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, iterator

I am trying code a numpy function where it organizes the `Appending_list` function below to a multi dimensional array for each iteration of `Values`. So in the first iteration is `Number_array + 0` for the first row and the second row is `Number_array + 1` and the third is `Number_array + 2`.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import random
Values = np.arange(0,3,1)
Number_array =  np.arange(1,5,1)
Appending_list = Number_array + Values * len(Number_array)
```

Expected Output

```
[[1,2,3,4], [2,3,4,5], [3,4,5,6]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking into broadcasting:

```
Appending_list = Number_array + Values[:,None]
```

Output:

```
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [2, 3, 4, 5],
       [3, 4, 5, 6]])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
values = np.arange(1, 5)
rows = 3
# creates 3 rows of `[1, 2, 3, 4]`
result = np.tile(values, rows).reshape((rows, len(values)))
shifts = np.arange(3)
# shifts the row values for each row by 0, 1, and 2 respectively
result += shifts[:,None]
```

Result

```
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [2, 3, 4, 5],
       [3, 4, 5, 6]])
```